# How to wrap option content to new line?

Tags: html, css

I have included a select in my webpage, but the options take much part of my screen. How can I make an option value wrap to the next line? Below is my code. I am using bootstrap. [You can see in the image that select is kind of taking 50% of screen when open.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRl7z.jpg)

Can anyone please suggest me, how to do it in a much better way?

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="collegeSelectOption">Select College</label>
     <div class="input-group">
     <select class="form-control custom-select" id="collegeSelectOption" name="collegeSelectOption">

         <!-- Some Php code to include options in my select -->             

     </select>
     <span class="input-group-btn">
          <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" name="collegeSelected" value="Go!">
     </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: for me, i was consider about set width for your options then overflow hide those addresses longer than standard width, and set tooltip for your options

Comment: Have you considered a plugin like select2, https://select2.github.io/ , where you have more control over the appearance of stuff in the drop down?

Comment: Thanks @Bindrid, it did work. Kudos to you. Select2 is the library I was looking for.